# Why does keycloak hide the "Service-account-admin-cli" user under "Users" section?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I was trying to call keycloak's REST api to create new users under a realm and I was following this tutorial:
https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/keycloak-rest-api-create-a-new-user/

I was able to configure the `Admin-cli` client as below:
[image]
and I was able to get the access token by using the client id and secret:
[image]

However, when I make a POST request to `/auth/admin/realms/myapp/users` with the bearer token, it fails to create a user and I got an "unknow_error"

I searched through the internet and community and documentation but there was no clue. Eventually after hours and hours of trying, I found a solution:

You need to first go to clients --> admin_cli --> Sessions:
[image]

Then click on the user "Service-account-admin-cli" and configure such that it has admin role
[image]

Then, the previous POST request will successfully create a new user.

I cannot understand why this user "Service-account-admin-cli" is hidden under the users section:
[image]

Why would it be hidden??? How are people supposed to find this user (Service-account-admin-cli) and configure it?  Does keycloak expect people to find it by clicking clients --> admin_cli --> Sessions and then see the user from there??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, one should avoid using the *master* Realm or touching the *admin_cli* configuration without a very good reason.

From the [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#the-master-realm) documentation one can read:

> When you boot Keycloak for the first time Keycloak creates a
> pre-defined realm for you. This initial realm is the master realm. It
> is the highest level in the hierarchy of realms. Admin accounts in
> this realm have permissions to view and manage any other realm created
> on the server instance. **When you define your initial admin account,
> you create an account in the master realm. Your initial login to the
> admin console will also be via the master realm.**
>
> **We recommend that you do not use the master realm to manage the users
> and applications in your organization.** Reserve use of the master realm
> for super admins to create and manage the realms in your system.
> Following this security model helps prevent accidental changes and
> follows the tradition of permitting user accounts access to only those
> privileges and powers necessary for the successful completion of their
> current task.

So typically, one would create a different realm and create the users there. Unless one wants to create *admin*-alike users.

---

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

That being said, to create the user using Keycloak's Rest API, one requests from the *admin-cli* client a token on behalf of the admin user, for instance:

```
TOKEN=$(curl -k -sS   -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
                      -d "username=$ADMIN_NAME" \
                      -d "password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD" \
                      -d "grant_type=password" \
                      https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token)
```

from the $TOKEN object extract the access token (let us named `$ACCESS_TOKEN`).

And then create the user as follows:

```
curl -k -sS -X POST https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/users \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
        -d "$USER_JSON_DATA"
```

`$USER_JSON_DATA` will be the json data representation of the user to be created. There is no need to add the role *admin* to the *master* admin deployed with Keycloak by default.

> Does keycloak expect people to find it by clicking clients -->
> admin_cli --> Sessions

If setup normally, you would just need to know (as I already described) the *admin's* name and password, which is configured in the initial setup anyway.

Following this setup then you:

> You need to first go to clients --> admin_cli --> Sessions:

you would see the following:

[image]

The difference now is that if you click on the *admin* user > roles, you would see the following:

[image]

The *admin* user, has already the *admin* role. No need for:

> configure such that it has admin role

Now if you change the *admin_cli* configuration exactly as you did then you need to add to the `Service-account-admin-cli` user the role admin.

> I cannot understand why this user "Service-account-admin-cli" is
> hidden under the users section:

It is an implementation detail; unfortunately, I could not find online a an explanation for that either. But I do agree that without further context, it does not look very user-friendly. Now that begs the question of why the tutorial did not warn their readers about it.

Now, if one speculate a bit, the reason to hide that user from the list of users could be because:

1. it is not a *real* user in the conventional sense; not meant to be used to login into Keycloak. If you try to set the password of that *user* you get always an error.
2. the list of users is for the users explicitly created for that realm that one can actually explicitly authenticate. In other words, "Service-account-admin-cli" is used so that it represents the "one" performing the call to the *admin-cli*, since when one changes the grand type from password to *client-credentials* there is no explicit user authentication anymore (*i.e.,* admin username and password). So "Service-account-admin-cli" is used as a place holder.

Naturally, one could argue, Why not just make "Service-account-admin-cli" have the admin role by default?!, but again, it is implementation details that only the developers behind them can justify.

Another good reason to not *blindly* change the original setup of the *admin-cli*.

Answer (score 0):

Just did the same tutorial and had the same problem. Thank you for your post! It helped me to figure out the solution. I don't know if that is due to a newer Keycloak-version but I don't even see the session of the service-account.

Instead of going through the session-menu you could instead go to:

clients -> admin-cli -> service account roles

And then add "manage-users" from:

client roles -> realm-management

I think that's how it's supposed to work.